# $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $g:Z\rightarrow Y$ then $h:X\times Z\rightarrow Y$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $\textbf{Lemma}$: If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Z\rightarrow Y$ are continuous functions with $X,Y,Z\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then $h:X\times Z\rightarrow Y$ via $h(x,z)=f(x)g(z)$ is continuous.

Is there a way to show the above that uses a combination of results that makes it not too difficult to prove?

I am trying to construct a homotopy and I have a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is some topological space, and I am composing the function
$$h:\left[0,1\right]\times \left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]\rightarrow [0,1] \text{ by } h(s,t)=3s(\frac{1}{3}-t) \text{ with } f.$$

I think it would be nice to prove the above general result and then apply it to the function $h$ in my problem and then have the lemma for future problems. This is mostly for my own confidence to be able to show such a thing is true, I doubt I need to go into details like this for my written turned in work. I am hoping I am overlooking some obvious things that will make proving the lemma easy. I know that if $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are continuous where $X,Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then $fg:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have established that projections are continuous, then you can consider the two compositions 
$$
X \times Z \to X \overset{f}{\to} Y
$$
and
$$
X \times Z \to Z \overset{g}{\to} Y
$$
and use your result that the pointwise product of the two maps is also continuous.

Answer (score 5):

Try to prove that the function $F:\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$, $F(x,y)=xy$ is continuous. Then use the fact $(x,z)\mapsto (f(x),g(z))$ is continuous and the composition of continuous functions are continuous.